# Conditional independence of dependent variables (D-Separation)

Tags: machine-learning, probability, bayesian

I have given the following Bayesian network and need to evaluate whether `q` is independent of `s` given `r`.

I know that the path over the node `r` is blocked because `r` is observed. But what about the other direct path? Probabilistically it states `P(s|q)`, therefore `q` is directly dependent on `s`. But does this also apply to conditional independence?

I do not have any probabilities given and need to solve the task using D-Separation. The problem is when we want to check if two variables are d-separated, we need to check whether the path is blocked. In the case of the lower path that includes `r` it is, because `r` is observed and we have a head-to-tail connection. But what case do we have for the other path? Here we do not have any nodes in between.

[image]

Comment: you probably have to check whether `P(q|c)*P(s|c) = P(q and s|c)`

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Only the model was given. I do not have the exact probabilities and need to solve it with D-separation. (I will make the question more clear)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \eqalign{
\textrm{Conditional independence} &\Leftrightarrow p(q,s|r) = p(q|r)p(s|r)\cr
p(q,s|r) &= p(s|q,r)p(q|r)\cr
p(s|q,r) &\ne p(s|r)\cr
}$$
(because observing $q$ and $r$ would tell us more about the distribution of $s$ than observing $r$ alone)
$$ \eqalign{
\Rightarrow p(s|q,r)p(q|r) &\ne p(q|r)p(s|r) \cr
\Rightarrow p(q,s|r) &\ne p(q|r)p(s|r)
}$$
$\Rightarrow$ $q$ and $s$ are not conditionally independent given $r$, I believe.

I have used only basic probability instead of D-separation in this answer, but I think it's important that you understand the basic probability before you start trying to understand D-separation.